# java stream - get the result after splitting string twice

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a String:

```
String modulesToUpdate = "potato:module1, tomato:module2";
```

I want to get from it only:

```
module1
module2
```

First I have to split it with "," and then with ":"

So, I did this:

```
String files[] = modulesToUpdate.split(",");

for(String file: files){
    String f[] = file.split(":");
    for(int i=0; i<f.length; i++){
        System.out.println(f[1])
    }
}
```

This works, but loop in the loop is not elegant.

I'm trying to do the same thing with streams.

So, I did this:

```
Stream.of(modulesToUpdate)
            .map(line -> line.split(","))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .flatMap(Pattern.compile(":")::splitAsStream)
            .forEach(f-> System.out.println(f.toString().trim()));
```

Output:

```
potato
module1
tomato
module2
```

How to reduce/filter it to get only:

```
module1
module2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change a single line:

```
  .map(x -> x.split(":")[1])
```

instead of:

```
  .flatMap(Pattern.compile(":")::splitAsStream)
```

Or as @Holger mentions in the comment:

```
 .map(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf(':')+1))
```

this does not create the intermediate array at all.

That `flatMap` is returning a `Stream` and Streams don't have indexes, but you do need them in this case to get to the second token.

Comment: or `.map(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf(':')+1))`, as it doesn’t create the array and irrelevant substrings in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

The `split` operation can do all your steps at once.

Consider splitting with the separator pattern `,\s*` instead of just `,` to get rid of the need for a subsequent `trim` operation. Likewise, we can treat the unwanted prefix (matching `[^:]*?:`) as part of the separator, to remove it.

There’s only one thing left; the first element has a prefix which is not treated as separator. We may do either, remove it manually before the stream operation

```
Pattern.compile(",\\s*[^:]*?:")
       .splitAsStream(modulesToUpdate.substring(modulesToUpdate.indexOf(':')+1))
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

or we allow a prefix at the beginning of the string to be treated like a separator, which lets the split operation handle it, but creates an empty string at the beginning, which we have to skip

```
Pattern.compile("(^|,\\s*)[^:]*?:").splitAsStream(modulesToUpdate)
       .skip(1)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `skip` inside `flatMap`, e.g.:

```
String modulesToUpdate = "potato:module1, tomato:module2";
Arrays.stream(modulesToUpdate.split(","))
.map(String::trim)
.flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(":")).skip(1))
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe another option can be:

1. split to multiple conditions
2. Stream the array and collect the elements at odd positions

---

```
String modulesToUpdate = "potato:module1, tomato:module2";
String[] mod = modulesToUpdate.split("[:,]");
List<String> res = IntStream.range(0, mod.length)
                     .filter(j -> (j % 2) == 0)
                     .mapToObj(i -> mod[i])
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(res);
```